# How do I search for screenshots of the lock and home screen on Apple Photos for Mac?

Tags: macos, photos.app, screen-capture, search

I would like to optimize my photo library by deleting screenshots of my of home screen and lock screen.

I use screenshots quite a bit for work, so looking through all of my screenshots would be quite tedious.

Is there a way to search for these screenshots on Apple Photos?